# Is the output of TreeForm expected to follow the level's of an expression?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an expression

```
a = Plus[Rational[2, 3], 
 Times[Rational[-1, 6], 
  Plus[1, Times[Complex[0, -1], Power[3, Rational[1, 2]]]], 
  Power[Times[Rational[1, 2], 
    Plus[-263, Times[3, Power[8277, Rational[1, 2]]]]], 
   Rational[1, 3]]], 
 Times[Rational[11, 3], Power[2, Rational[-2, 3]], 
  Plus[1, Times[Complex[0, 1], Power[3, Rational[1, 2]]]], 
  Power[Plus[-263, Times[3, Power[8277, Rational[1, 2]]]], 
   Rational[-1, 3]]]]
```

then I apply a TreeForm

```
TreeForm[a]
```

[image: TreeForm[a]]

First question: Why does not the Rational show as Rational[2,3], as it does in the Wolfram Demo Project at: 'https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LevelsOfAMathematicaExpression/'

[image: From public wolfram site]

I have read that Rational is an Atomic, but I don't get why the demo shows one detail, and the application currently shows differently. I realize different versions are different, but I am unsure of the reason for this behavior.

I am trying to learn to Map at various levels and when I am reading the TreeForm output, I cannot map the output to the input as I was thinking it should be.

My second question is: Does the TreeForm always show the graphic output with the levels going from top to bottom and then from left to right. I ask this as when I map a function to the Rational at the start of the expression, it moves the Rational to the far right in the output of TreeForm. As in the following picture.

As I am trying to solidify my understanding of the levels for Map and such, I could use a pointer or two as the output is not making sense to me.

```
TreeForm[MapAt[g, a, {{1}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: use `a = Defer @ Plus[...]` or  `a = HoldForm @ Plus[...]`  to define `a`.

Comment: @kglr thanks.. that helped me understand the levels much better. Thanks again.